# Change Category Label Location to Outside of Chart Area

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm working with a pretty simple Kendo UI Chart.

When the values go below zero, the axis labels stay near the zero axis. This caused the text and bars to overlap, which is not optimal.

I would like to get the labels to show up at the bottom of the chart area. Any one know how to do this?

See below, where the 'Approved' text is overlapping with the grey bar. I'd like the label at the bottom of the chart area.

[image: Image of Kendo Chart]

Answer (score 3):

@gman, what you're looking for is the `axisCrossingValues`.

```
valueAxis: {
  min: -10,
  max: 10,
  // Keeps the default axis at the 0 crossing point
  // and moves the "label" axis to the very bottom
  axisCrossingValues: [0, -10]
}
```

Take a look at a code sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/design48/7C3nP/ and change the `axisCrossingValues` y-coordinate to `-8` or something. Hope that helps.